# ATmega32 SRAM and EEPROM difference

Tags: memory, embedded, microcontroller, ram, non-volatile

So from what I have read SRAM is volatile and EEPROM is non volatile. If SRAM is volatile, how come I sometimes get values (random and garbage but still values) when I use *ptr.

For example for ptr=&x, *ptr might give me a value. Shouldn't I get NULL because it is volatile and SRAM is wiped out every time the power is off?

Comment: SRAM and EEPROM refer to specific memory technologies, but the question applies to all memory technologies, which can be broadly divided into volatile and non-volatile.

Answer (score 4):

Volatile, in the terms of memory, means that values won't get preserved after a power cycle. Given the nature of RAM, it may contain any garbage value at the point of power-up. There is nothing in the hardware that initializes RAM to zero.

So you will have to initialize RAM to zero manually if this is needed.

The C standard actually mandates that such initialization is done on all variables with static storage duration - but those only. That "zero-out" initialization is carried out by some firmware before `main()` is executed. But local C variables will never get initialized automatically.

Please note that the `volatile` keyword in C has little to do with volatile memories. Don't confuse those two different terms.

Answer (score 0):

No. You mixing contexts. One thing is memory volatility, it concerns the memory physical construction. Other is your code reading random memory address.

Sometimes hardware can wipe a SRAM on power up, sometimes not, you cannot count on it.

If you read non occupied address of the RAM in your code you will read garbage, either bits generated powering process or old data that was disposed and is no longer used in the same power cycle.